# Where are the CURLOPT_* constants defined for the curl_easy_setopt function?

Tags: libcurl

I've looked at practically every file included in the libcurl source package and can't seem to find where the CURLOPT_* options are defined. I gather that they're probably integers, perhaps an enum, but for the life of me I can't find them.

The language I'm writing in is RealBasic, if that matters at all. Generally when using an external library written in C I need to manually find and translate the various `#define` blocks in the headers. But I have to know where the `#define` block is before I can do anything!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They're defined with the CINIT() macro within the curl/curl.h header file. In a very recent such file (as of me writing this) they start at line 782.

The macro actually creates a line within a big enum construct.

Comment: Excellent! That seems to have given me the toehold I needed. Thanks!

Comment: Aaaand I've successfully downloaded a test file! I owe you a beer, good sir.

Comment: happy to see you made progress!

Comment: :) Not sure why I didn't upvote before, but a year late is better than never!